# How will the beta be evaluated?

Tags: discussion

Our Area51 page says that the site's status will be evaluated in 7 days.  What's going to happen then?  Is this "promote or shut down", or might the beta continue, or what?  (I see the five criteria and our progress against them, but I don't know how that turns into a decision and what the likely outcomes are.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site will not be shut down in 7 days. The 90 day beta is a *minimum* requirement before a site can graduate. The vast majority of sites need more time to build up a critical mass of users, questions, participation, and traffic.

You can read much more about that process and what those Area 51 numbers mean here:

[**Does this site have a chance of succeeding?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

Make special note of the sections that describe *what* you can do to help your site get closer to graduation. Other sites have had a lot of success with these techniques.

Comment: Thanks.  I was confused because other betas I'm following just say they'll continue "indefinitely", but we had a date.  The others are older, so I guess they hit 90 days and moved into "indefinite" and we probably will to?

Comment: @Monica, That's what I'm expecting to  happen.